# progressDialog in wrong tab

Tags: android, tabs, progressdialog

I have 4 tabs in my application. One of them is for json parsing with progress dialog. But i see progres dialog at another tab.
[image]

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_parsing, container, false);
    lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list);
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(lv.getContext(), null, getResources().getString(R.string.connecting), true, true);
    MyTask myTask = new MyTask(FragmentParsing.this);
    myTask.execute(url);

    return view;
}

    @Override
public void onTaskComplete(ArrayList<String> array) {
    if(array != null) {
        //adapter.clear();
        arrayList.addAll(array);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    else
        Toast.makeText(getView().getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.fuck), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    if (progressDialog != null && progressDialog.isShowing()) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

And i want to see icons to left of text. Not above.

Code from MainActivity

```
private void setUI(){
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        if (toolbar != null){
            toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        }
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_list_white_18dp).setText(R.string.listtab));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_camera_alt_white_18dp).setText(R.string.scalingtab));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_web_asset_white_18dp).setText(R.string.parsingtab));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_my_location_white_18dp).setText(R.string.maptab));

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        TabAdapter tabAdapter = new TabAdapter(fragmentManager, 4);
        viewPager.setAdapter(tabAdapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do include your codes for the community to analyze :)

Comment: it's happening because of `setOffscreenPageLimit`. You have to overwrite the default `ViewPager` and make the limit 0 .

Comment: @ZahidulIslam Please tell me how it's done

Comment: Post ur fragments pager or view pager code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its basically android pager workflow. It always creates one adjacent page view as soon as you swipe. You can have logger and check. If I'm not not wrong your fragment pager, you start your progress bar on `onResume callback` of your fragment.

Comment: For performance n cleaner navigation your fragment onCreateView will called well before even its an adjacent fragment. Since all view contexts related activity there is no doubt that your progress dialog will be shown. As solution to your put your progress dialog show code in 'onResume' callback of your fragment

Answer (score 1):

First:

```
public class MyApp extends Application { 
      public Boolean isLoaded = false; 
      public Boolean getIsLoaded(){  
           return isLoaded; 
      } 

     public void setIsLoaded(Boolean isLoaded){ 
       this.isLoaded = isLoaded;
     } 
}
```

And in your fragment side, you can perform this:

```
Boolean status;
status = ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).getIsLoaded();
if(!status){
 //show your dialog
 //get your data
 ((MyApp) getActivity().getApplication()).setIsLoaded(true);
}
```

I hope you can take reference from the above code.

Comment: can you expand your answer?

Comment: On onViewCreated method you can perform  the status check and decide whether to show your progress dialog or not.Then after loading your data, set your boolean status setIsLoaded true.

Comment: @Riten its issue is not with app loading, its the behaviour of pager. Its adjacent page well in advance. so the on create view of the fragment get called.

Comment: @sush you can define Progressbar in the xml and use it in your required fragment.That will solve your original question/ issue.

Answer (score 0):

Progress dialog is an independent window. It will show until discarded. If the context which created it is nullified,  it will throw exception of leaked window. In your fragment's onPause, check for nullability of progress dialog and dismiss it. You can also check whether the task is still running if you want to show window again in onResume, provided user navigated back to this fragment.
In any case, if you want progress to only be shown in specific fragment while loading views,  you might want to consider using ProgressBar instead and set its visibility accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use this override method of fragment it load data only once and for each fragment when it is open.

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {}
```

as

```
 @Override
    public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
        super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
        if (isVisibleToUser && !isApiCalled) {
          //call the api and load data
            isApiCalled = true;
        }
    }
```